# Show only "in stock" related products on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I would like to show only "in stock" related products on WooCommerce single product pages.

I know I can override `single-product/related.php` template file via My theme. Here below is the related code for this template:

```php
<section class="related products">

    <h2><?php _e( 'You May Also Want', 'MyStore' ); ?></h2>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>

            <?php
                $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

                setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

</section>
```

---

Is it possible making some changes to this file to only show "in stock" related products on WooCommerce single product page? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of editing template files, you can use `woocommerce_product_related_posts_query` dedicated filter hook to alter the query excluding "out of stock" products from displayed related products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', 'alter_product_related_posts_query', 10, 3 );
function alter_product_related_posts_query( $query, $product_id, $args ){
    global $wpdb;

    $query['join']  .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id ";
    $query['where'] .= " AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND meta_value != 'outofstock' ";

    return $query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Customize related products with a custom meta query in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916699/customize-related-products-with-a-custom-meta-query-in-woocommerce/53918057#53918057)

Comment: @MohamedAliSamali Sorry but this code works and display only related products that are not outofstock, that is what you asked in your question… For your problem, you might need sometimes to go in WooCommerce settings > Status > Tools *(tab)* and in **"WooCommerce transients"** you should click on **"Clear transients"**.

Comment: add_filter works but it hide  everything. I think it takes just the 4 or 5 first products ... if the 4th or 5th first products are out of stock it will not show anything. but in my case product 6, 7 ... are NOT out of stock.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've been using, and it works for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'mysite_filter_related_products', 10, 1 );
function mysite_filter_related_products( $related_product_ids )
{

if (!is_admin()) {
    foreach ($related_product_ids as $key => $value) {
        $relatedProduct = wc_get_product($value);
        if (!$relatedProduct->is_in_stock() ) {
            unset($related_product_ids["$key"]);
        }
    }

    return $related_product_ids;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Because when the 4 first products are out of stock it does not display anything (In case the default 4 products are shown) **you could use the following snippet instead of overwriting the template file**.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_related_products( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {    
    foreach( $related_posts as $key => $related_post ) {        
        // Get product
        $related_product = wc_get_product( $related_post );
        
        // Is a WC product 
        if ( is_a( $related_product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            // Stock status
            $stock_status = $related_product->get_stock_status();
            
            // NOT instock
            if ( $stock_status != 'instock' ) {
                unset( $related_posts[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $related_posts;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'filter_woocommerce_related_products', 10, 3 );
```

---

---

**Overwriting the template file**

There are always multiple solutions but 1 of them could be by overwriting the template file.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/single-product/related.php

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php`

---

Replace

```
<?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>

        <?php
        $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

        setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

With

```php
<?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>

    <?php
    $stock_status = $related_product->get_stock_status();

    if ( $stock_status == 'instock' ) {
        
        $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

        setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```