# Hide “out of stock” related products on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I need a little help, please.
I want to hide the products that are no longer in stock, only in the related products area, from single product pages.
I created it and everything is ok, but I can't hide it in the related area, any changes I make don't work.
Existing codes do not work in my case.
Thank you.

I used these to create the "out of stock" badge:

```php
//Add an out of stock overlay to product images when all variations are unavailable
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
    global $product;
    if ( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo '<span class="sold-out-overlay">Stoc epuizat</span>';
    }
});
```

```css
/*Sold out badge automat in*/
.sold-out-overlay {
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute ;
    right: 5px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice tutorial which does what you want: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/hide-out-of-stock-products.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use CSS, you can use the `woocommerce_related_products` filter hook instead.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_related_products( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {    
    foreach( $related_posts as $key => $related_post ) {        
        // Get product
        $related_product = wc_get_product( $related_post );
        
        // Is a WC product 
        if ( is_a( $related_product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            // Stock status
            $stock_status = $related_product->get_stock_status();
            
            // Out of stock
            if ( $stock_status == 'outofstock' ) {
                unset( $related_posts[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $related_posts;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'filter_woocommerce_related_products', 10, 3 );
```

---

Related: [Show only “in stock” related products on WooCommerce single product page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64550445/11987538)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I also tried this code, but only one or two related products appear now, compared to the 4 that have the theme defined.

Comment: Then that is because you either have very few related products or because a lot of products are out of stock. This is the disadvantage of hiding products.
For example, if there are 20 related products, then 17 may already be out of stock before this problem occurs.

Comment: It is true that there are many products out of stock, but from the 94 products in total, which are currently picked up in the shop, 42 are in stock.

Comment: My code says **for any related product out of stock, hide it**. I cannot add more to that. If you only have 2 related products of a given product, then it won't show 4 there either, even without my code. In short, if you always want to display a minimum of 4 products, then you have to fill the 'empty products' with unrelated products.