# WooCommerce - Set priorities for related products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am wondering if there is a way to set priorities for related products.

I am trying to get them with some kind of priority. First by Tags -> then by Brand (custom field) --> then if not enough products are found from tags & brand I would like to let the Categories fill up the rest.

I've only seen codes to disable categories or tags alltogether, like this one:

```
// remove categories
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms', 'remove_related_product_categories', 10, 2 );
function remove_related_product_categories( $terms_ids, $product_id  ){
    return array();
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how can I start working towards it?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this is a start point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916699/customize-related-products-with-a-custom-meta-query-in-woocommerce/53918057#53918057) for your brands (custom field)…

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec, that led me to a series of thinkings.
I ended up writing 3 different `wp-query`, prioritizing tags, then fill-up the rest with brand (if any), then fill-up the rest with category.
For example: Query 1 --> 1 result; Query 2 --> 2 results -->`array_merge` with Query 1 results, and so on.